# ObservableArray not notifying when item changed

Tags: asp.net, knockout.js

I try to bind `observableArray` to `div` on my page and everything is ok. This array contains simple `JSON` objects, not observable, obtained from `WebService`.

After that, I want to be able to modify those objects in array and would like view to be refreshed with each modification. For example, when checkbox gets clicked I would like to change the flag on my `JSON` object (this seems to work automatically all right) and at the same time my UI should get updated, which does not happen. Could anyone provide me with the reason (is this because those objects are simple, not observable?) and solution?

```
    var DocumentContentModel = function () {
        var self = this;
        self.content = ko.observableArray();
        self.ElementApprovalChanged = function (element) {
            DocumentService.DoSomething(
                element.Id,
                function (result) {
                    if (!result) {
                        var negatedApproved = !element.Approved;
                        element.Approved = negatedApproved;
                    }
                },
                function (error) {
                    alert(error);
                });
            return true;
        };
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var contentModel = new ContentModel();
        DocumentService.GetContent(1,
        function (result) {
            contentModel.content(JSON.parse(result));
        });

        ko.applyBindings(contentModel);
    });
```

UI

```
<div class="ContentContainer">
    <div data-bind='foreach: content'>
        <div class="ContentElement" data-bind='css: { NotApproved: !Approved} '>
           <div class="ContentValue" data-bind='html: Value'></div>
            <div class="Approval">
                <input type="checkbox" data-bind='checked: Approved, click: $root.ElementApprovalChanged' />
            </div>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

What is happening is on checkbox click I send request to webservice and if this call returns false I want to reset element's `Approved` flag. And even whithout that, selecting checkbox should change `div` class attribute to mark it as `NotApproved` when needed. But none of this happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An observableArray only tracks the array. So if something is added, removed or replaced in the array this will trigger an update to your view.

An observableArray does NOT track the state of individual properties on the items in the array. So if you have an `Approved` flag on your objects this needs to be an observable for the UI to reflect changes to that property.

So you would have something like:

```
element.Approved = ko.observable(false);
....
....

if (!result) {                         
  var negatedApproved = !element.Approved();                         
  element.Approved(negatedApproved);                     
}
```

(or if you want to be more consise:

```
element.Approved(!element.Approved());
```

)

Comment: Yes, but I obtained all those elements in array from `WebService` and I cannot change them (or can I? I'm far from being an expert on `javascript`). So I would like to know if there is any way to reevaluate array bindings.

Comment: No problem, Pako. You need the knockout mappings plugin which is for the very purpose of converting JSON to ko objects and back again. See the documentation here at http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html